# Return either Date or the position of first text not in range

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-2010, formulas

I have been searching for this answer for hours and can't find anything.  Please help.

I am trying to write a formula that will return either the position of text in a cell or the date associated with that text (the date is the ultimately output but I can get there if I have the position).

The data is as follows:

- Column A contains a list of helpdesk ticket numbers.
- Column B contains the text output of the ticket comment history (the column is called Internal Work Notes).  Each update is stamped with the following string:  **mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss - person's name (Work Notes)**.  See example of contents of cell B2 below.
- On another page, I have a table called "MergedList" that contains a list of our team members names.  Let's assume that table includes the name John Smith.

In column C, I would like to capture the date of the first entry made by someone **NOT** on the MergedList table (using the example cell contents below, I'd want "09-25-2017" to be shown in C2 (i.e. Mary Jones because we don't care about the updates made by John Smith).

The problem is that everything I have found on the web relates to finding the position of text that IS on the list.  I need the position of text NOT on the list.

Note:  In another column, I did need to return the result of the most recent update by someone that is on the list and I did so using this array formula:

```
{=IFERROR(MID([@[Internal Work Notes]],FIND(INDEX(MergedList,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MergedList,[@[Internal Work Notes]])),0)),[@[Internal Work Notes]])-22,10),"--")}
```

This returned the date (which was 22 places behind the position).

The other formula I tried was to extract the person's name from the text as follows:

```
=MID([@[Internal Work Notes]],SEARCH(" - ",[@[Internal Work Notes]])+3,SEARCH(" (Work Notes)",[@[Internal Work Notes]])-23)
```

But that simply returned the name of the person who most recently updated the ticket.

I assume the final formula will in some way combine the two above but I don't know how to 'negate' the formula(s).  Help?

---

**Example of cell B2 contents:**

10-09-2017 13:09:10 – John Smith (Work Notes)
for scan to folder function, software is required on any PC.

The PC/Server which has this software must was rebuilt or retired.

09-28-2017 06:30:11 - John Smith (Work Notes)
Waiting for Mike Nelson information

09-25-2017 08:17:16 – Mary Jones (Work Notes)
since file share issues were solved just minutes after our meeting, we were able to do the testing onsite.

Testing with different shared folder went wrong and did not work. We will be doing further tests with spare laptop and different configuration. Meanwhile we will have the border team check the authentication.

09-24-2017 07:25:01 – Tony Harris (Work Notes)
File Server is currently down, so no testing can be done in Sofia

Comment: I hate to say this, but: What have you tried? Please read the FAQ about how to ask a question. Then edit your question and turn it into something that CAN be answered. Otherwise, you'll find this question will be closed pretty soon.

Comment: I created a variation of the formula (in another column) that pulled the first occurrence of someone that WAS on the list:  =IFERROR(MID([@[Internal Work Notes]],FIND(INDEX(MergedList,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MergedList,[@[Internal Work Notes]])),0)),[@[Internal Work Notes]])-22,10),"--").

Comment: And I have the formula to extract the data between the " - " and "(work notes)":  =MID([@[Internal Work Notes]],SEARCH(" - ",[@[Internal Work Notes]])+3,SEARCH(" (Work Notes)",[@[Internal Work Notes]])-23)

Comment: I just haven't found a way to combine them and turn it into a "NOT".

Comment: Which part of "edit your question" did you not understand? Don't post formulas in comments. Please find out how this site works before posting any more

Comment: Please don't be rude.  I don't know how to simplify my request any more and still get the dilemma across.  If it was easy to explain, I wouldn't need to post it.

Comment: @teylyn was expressing that fact that your comments above should be put in the original post using [edit] and not a comment.  Comments cannot be formatted and are hard  to read at times.

Comment: I tried rewriting the post based on what it said in the help file (although I'm not sure if the formulas are any clearer.  Is there a special way to do formulas???).

Comment: Are you opposed to using a custom VBA function for this?

Comment: Are all of the lines you have listed under **Example of cell B2 contents** in `B2` or are they in multiple cells?

Comment: Kaciree:  I prefer not to use VBA if possible but if it turns out there is no way to do it, even with helper columns, I may have no choice.

Comment: Ron:  The example I gave represent the contents of a single cell.  The report has over 1,000 tickets each day and each ticket has the complete Work Notes contents in one cell.  Thus, I would not be able to practically break the contents of each Internal Work Notes cell into separate cells.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do this with multiple helper columns and worksheet functions, but it would be cumbersome, inflexible and difficult to maintain.

Here is a User Defined Function (UDF) that will return the first instance where the name is not in the list found in `MergedList`.  You can optionally return either the name, or the date.

It depends on the string pattern being exactly as you show it with regard to the date/time stamp, and also with a `Name` having only two words.  If the name is different, then the pattern will need to be adjusted.

The patterns are defined as Regular Expressions.

```
Option Explicit
Function NewName_Date(sInput As String, rNameList As Range, Optional ReturnName As Boolean = False) As Variant
    'RegexPattern
    Const sPat As String = "((?:\d{2}-){2}\d{4})\s(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\W+(\w+\s+\w+)"
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Dim R As Range

NewName_Date = "" 'Empty string if nothing found

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    .ignorecase = True

    If .Test(sInput) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(sInput)
        For Each M In MC
            Set R = rNameList.Find(what:=M.submatches(1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
            If R Is Nothing Then
                Select Case ReturnName
                    Case True
                        NewName_Date = M.submatches(1)
                    Case False
                        NewName_Date = M.submatches(0)
                End Select
            End If
        Next M
    End If
End With

End Function
```

The formula, on the worksheet, might look like:

```
C2:  =NewName_Date([@[Internal Work Notes]],MergedList,FALSE)
```

To return the matching name, merely change `FALSE` to `TRUE`

[image]

Comment: I've only used a RegEx formula once and didn't understand it.  While the date/time string is a definite number of characters, the names are not...some names may be 1 word or be as many as 4 words.  thus, I would have no idea how to modify the code, let alone troubleshoot it later.  :(

Comment: There are ways of handling that.  But it would be easiest if there was a definite pattern.  For example, will the name always be followed by the phrase `(Work Notes)` as you show in your example?  If so, changing the Regex to take that into account would be easy.  If not, there may be other solutions, but they would take more time.